# Jmeter - extract json data from dynamic payload using 'and' statement

Tags: json, jmeter

I want to extract value from dynamic JSON.

This generation is different every time when is executed.
I need to get ex: XLIfccMNLv1asVam3QuatowCmrp8IYuE0FUDMYncegs= 
which is generated in the different location in the Json file, with different value

I tried with.

`$.payload[?(@.eventType == 'AAA')].entityId`

which is working fine.
But, i want more stronger query.

Is it possible to use && statement with the query something like:

```
$.payload[?(@.eventType == 'AAA')&&(@.outgoingCurrency== 'EUR')].entityId
```

My payload:

```
{
   "payload":[
      {
         "entityId":"qvr_IlDhTdzldeccxguNR84sE0N78DUfNGzwH-3pY7Y=",
         "accountHolderId":"dvwxpTxVHdo2n1d5ytO6WyhnI2nuaEuzsh47agPpSFU=",
         "processorType":"DUMMY",
         "eventType":"AAA",
         "outgoingCurrency":"USD",
         "holdPeriodInHours":11,
         "disabled":false
      },
      {
         "entityId":"XLIfccMNLv1asVam3QuatowCmrp8IYuE0FUDMYncegs=",
         "accountHolderId":"Xoo8uAM90qRT7kceDUJBIIqafUuUdH2fH_Ia2z1TY5w=",
         "processorType":"DUMMY",
         "eventType":"BBB",
         "outgoingCurrency":"EUR",
         "holdPeriodInHours":10,
         "disabled":false
      },
      {
         "entityId":"yBoHvYkyszaQpaFe1zvqCY416_vYiq7iivA9bWJhiTg=",
         "processorType":"BMO_CPR",
         "eventType":"AAA",
         "disabled":false
      }

   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the operation **&&** inside the expression: 
$.payload[?(@.outgoingCurrency== 'EUR' && @.eventType == 'AAA')].entityId.

For more details see: https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/